# Getting SOAP answer from localhost

Tags: apache, perl, soap

I am learning SOAP and have created a very small CGI script which runs on Apache that will offer a small set of functions.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;

SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI   
  -> dispatch_to('Demo')     
  -> handle;

package Demo;

sub hi {                     
  return "hello, world";     
}

sub bye {                    
  return "goodbye, cruel world";
}

sub languages {                 
  return ("Perl", "C", "sh");   
}
```

My client is

```
#!perl -w

use SOAP::Lite;

print SOAP::Lite                                             
    -> uri('http://localhost:80/cgi-bin/Demo')                                             
    -> proxy('http://localhost:80/cgi-bin/hibye.cgi')
    -> hi()                                                    
    -> result;
```

Everything compiles and there are no errors when I run the scripts. The problem is that when I run the client it finishes, but it doesn't get a response. I think that the URI might be wrong, but I am not sure. The proxy is fine.

Edit: I wasn't getting errors when running the scripts in the console, however I was getting errors in the apache log (which for some reason I did not check).
The error **was**

```
script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hibye.cgis
```

It was a permission problem. I fixed it and now I when running the script no problem appears neither in the console, neither in the error log.

In the access log I get the following:

```
"POST /cgi-bin/hibye.cgi HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "SOAP::Lite/Perl/0.714"
```

Comment: You will not be alerted to many significant errors unless you use strict and use warnings at the top of your code and after any package declarations. The command (or shebang) line -w qualifier is inferior in many ways to use warnings, and you should use the latter as a matter of course.

Comment: I did that and now I am actually getting an error. Might as well write this as an answer, since I might be able to fix the error. Even if I can't fix it, it will most likely require major changes to the question so might as well write a different one. (if it is needed)

Comment: Edit: Turns out that the error was very silly (permissions) and once I fixed it I was back to this error again. This time there is nothing in the apache log.

Comment: You need to tell us what *"this error again"* is, as all you have said so far is that *"there are no errors when I run the scripts"* and *"now I am actually getting an error"*. You have never mentioned the contents of the Apache log before.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I will update it in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I found out the problem - it was in the uri binding. In this case it must be changed from:

```
http://localhost:80/cgi-bin/Demo
```

to:

```
http://localhost:80/Demo
```

and the script will work like it is supposed to.